# Pixel-based image classification (Orthoimage or Raw image?

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, digital-image-processing, orthorectification

I am studying image classification and wanted to produce some land cover maps.
However, i can not seem to find resources that states whether you need to geometrically correct (orthorectification) your raw satellite  image first before you conduct your image classification or its ideal to use the raw satellite image data to retain the original pixels for a more effective image classification.

Does it depend on the type of classification whether pixel-based or object-based classification?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! What imagery are you working with?

Comment: Hello Aaron, thank you! planning to use Sentinel or Spot image.